# Call a F# Function in VB (or C# or whatever)

Tags: visual-studio, f#

It seems I am not able to call a dummy function created in F# from C# and/or VB.Net in Visual Studio 2010 Beta 1.

Most references dug up by Google resolve issues arising in older versions of Visual Studio and CTPs of F#.

It would rock if somebody could post a small howto. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

F#:

```
// in Program.fs, last file in project
let Foo() =
    printfn "Hello from F#"
```

C#:

```
Program.Foo();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I found out I had a problem with F# namespaces, modules, and referencing the F# project.

Answer (score 3):

F#:

```
namespace MyFSharpCode

type MyType() =
    static member Foo() =
        printfn "Hello from F#"
```

C#:

```
MyFSharpCode.MyType.Foo();
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to make the F# code publicly available to other callers by [encapsulating it in a type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233205(VS.100).aspx).

Comment: -1. this is one way to do it, but it's not _needed_: functions defined at the top level are exposed as public static members on a class with the same name as the enclosing module.